# Browser opens both javascript:void(0) and onclick link

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, href

I have an image embedded within an anchor tag in HTML. The problem is that, when I click the image, I have two tabs that open instead of one.

**Problem**:

Two tabs are opened, one with the correct link, the other is a blank tab (`about:blank` in the address bar).

**Relevant sample code**:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');">
   <img src="..." />
</a>
```

**What I've tried**:

Immediately, I see that the `onclick` event is missing `return false;` and so I add it. Now the `window.open` function is followed by `return false;`, but the issue persists.

I tried replacing the `javascript:void(0);` with `#` in the `href`, but the issue remains - only this time instead of a blank tab, I get a new tab with the same content that I had in the tab where the link was clicked.

I also tried replacing the `javascript:void(0)` with `javascript:;`, but that has the same result.

Additionally, I tried using `event.preventDefault();` - again, did not get the desired results.

**Workaround**:

I've found that if I remove the `href` attribute and only have the `onclick` one, it works as expected. While this delivers the wanted results, I don't really like it. I also know that using `javascript:void(0)` is not considered good practice either, but I don't make all the decisions here.

**Points of note**:

- This only happens on Firefox and IE (v27 and v11). In Chrome it works
  fine.
- The code comes from an XSLT stylesheet, but the generated XHTML
  looks the same as the sample code.
- `<img>` element does not contain anything that would affect this.

Do you folks have any idea why this may be happening? Any solutions? I'd prefer not to use any 3rd party libraries, although jQuery is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue in firefox (see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/27LLV/).  Are you sure there are no other click events being bound to this element?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `target="_blank"` on your `<a>`?

Comment: @WillP - sadly I am not sure, this is a gigantic codebase. However, I will do even deeper investigation. 

Ian, yes I am sure.

Comment: If it makes it any easier, try using the developer tools "inspect element" functionality in chrome or Firefox (with Firebug) to view any event handlers on this element (and any wrapper elements)

Comment: Yep, trust me, I've been staring at the Firefox Inspector for the past several hours, and I couldn't find anything. However, I'll keep looking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this, the problem was that the `<img>` tag had a deeply-enrooted onClick event handler attached to it. So whenever I clicked the `<a>` tag, I called two onclick actions - the one from the `<a>` tag, and the other from the `<img>` one. I solved this problem by calling a new JS function and attaching it to the `<a>` tag, passing event as a param, and the function contains the `event.stopPropagation();`